# Are there any iOS libraries that allow a POST message to be sent asynchronously and reliably?

Tags: ios, ios5

I'm wanting to send some data to a web service which takes POST data.

However, if the internet connection drops then I need to queue the data. I.e. cache it and send it at the next available opportunity.

Are there any iOS libraries out there that might help with this?

At the moment I'm planning to do this using ASIFormDataRequest and, if that fails, store the data using NSUserDefaults. Then, I assume I'd need to complete the process in the background by:

- looking out for a connection using an NSOperation that flags up a connection with an NSNotification
- read the data from NSUserDefaults
- send this data
- remove the data from NSUserDefaults

Doesn't seem like a huge amount of work but am I re-inventing the wheel here or is this the best way to proceed?

Comment: Not sure, but perhaps RestKit does this? https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the AFNetworking Framework at Github, this may be what you are looking for: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

Answer (score 0):

I usually end up using ASIFormDataRequest and use NSThread to detach a new thread as well for the call. I then make it call my own delegate/protocol once it's done:

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"some_url"]];
[request setUseKeychainPersistence:YES];
[request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json"];
for (NSString *key in dictionary) {
    [request setPostValue:[dictionary objectForKey:key] forKey:key];
}
[request startSynchronous];
if([request responseStatusCode] == 200)
{
    NSString *response = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [request responseString]];
    if ([self _isValidDelegateForSelector:@selector(requestSucceeded)]) {
        [_delegate requestSucceeded];
    }
    if ([self _isValidDelegateForSelector:@selector(itemAdded:)]) {
        [_delegate itemAdded:[response JSONValue]];
    }
}
else {
    if ([self _isValidDelegateForSelector:@selector(requestFailedWithError:)])
        NSLog(@"%@", [request debugDescription]);
    [_delegate requestFailedWithError:[request error]];
}
```

This is all done in my own 'API' object that contains all the calls to the webs service, and hence why I called `startSynchronous` instead of asynchronous as I handle this in a different thread anyway.